# MacOS equivalent for Ubuntu Linker (ld) command?

Tags: command-line, big-sur, error

I'm following some tutorials from 2015, and in it you run this Linker command:

```sh
ld -T linker.ld -melf_i386 loader.o -o kernel.elf
```

I get this error:

```
ld: unknown option: -T
```

I tried to replace it with `ld --script=linker.ld -melf_i386 loader.o -o kernel.elf`, but this error: `ld: unknown option: --script=linker.ld`

After now looking through `man ld`, it seems neither of these are options. This tutorial was designed for Ubuntu, what would be the MacOS equivalent?

If it matters, I am on an Intel Big Sur machine.

Comment: if you use Homebrew, i believe that coreutils includes a gnu version of ld. `brew install coreutils`

Comment: I'll give it a shot.

Comment: In /usr/opt/coreutils/bin/ (my install location), there is no 'gld' or 'ld' program. What else myight it be @MatthewBarclay

Comment: What does -T do? Maybe the option is just not available in ld on macOS

Comment: It's for the script. Equivalent to --script=SCRIPT. I'm going off this list: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html

Comment: Why did you ask the question? The link you provide in your above comment answers your question.

Comment: @DavidAnderson No it does not. The MacOS version of `ld` does not work in this case, and I don't know a viable replacement.

Comment: But your link instructs you to use `gcc` instead of `ld`. I tested and this seems to work, although I do not think the `-melf_i386` option exists. User nohillside asks what `-T` does and `gcc` has the `-T` option. See `gcc --help`.

Comment: A general note macOS tends to use Xcode and clang as its C tools not gcc - so a GNU/Linux based tutorial is often not the best way to start. gcc is only needed in special cases.

Comment: Actually, `/usr/bin/gcc` and `/usr/bin/clang` are different files, but `cmp /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/clang` returns that the files have identical contents. `man gcc` returns nothing, but `man clang` does. However, the `-T` option does not appear in `man clang`, but does exist and also appears in `clang -help`. I should mention that I only have the command line developer tools installed in macOS 11.2. I do not have Xcode installed.

Comment: @DavidAnderson `-melf_i386` is `-m` with the option `elf_i386`.

Answer (score 1):

Linker scripts can be used with the GNU version of `ld` to customise how you want your program to be linked. Essentially not all customizations can be made with command line arguments, and instead you specify them in a linker script.

The `ld` command on macOS on the other hand allows you to specify all the possible customizations through the command line arguments. Therefore linker scripts are not used and not supported.

If you really want to find an "equivalent" option to `-T`, it would be `@`. You can go `ld @file [...]` and the contents of the file named `file` will be added to the command line arguments. It does not give you further possibilities for customisation than those already available as command line arguments.

Note that linker scripts made for the GNU version of `ld` cannot be used with the standard macOS supplied version of `ld`.

Comment: I am still not completely sure what I should be doing. `ld @linker.ld -melf_i386 loader.o -o kernel.elf` returns `ld: file not found: ENTRY(loader)`

Comment: As I wrote in the answer, you cannot use your linker script with this ld. Stop trying. Instead make a new question and explain what it is you want to achieve with your linker script, and you can be helped on how to implement that with this ld.

Comment: This will not work especially if you are trying to do kernel stuff. Not only are macOS tools different (the options for ld) but the kernel is totally different. You are really going down deep sidetracks - what are you actually trying to do that makes you want to use that tutorial

Comment: And more macos does not know what a elf format executable is - macOS uses Mach-O format

Comment: @mmmmmm Nothing here indicates any type of kernel work. You're not customizing linker scripts when developing for the Linux or macOS kernel.

Comment: Sorry the output file name -o kernel.elf made me think it is kernel - anyway elf is a problem on its own for user level code.l

Comment: @mmmmmm GNU ld is not limited to only supporting ELF. It also supports other formats such as COFF, XCOFF, etc.

Comment: Yes, I can understand the file name hinting that way - however the question also specifies that he wans "-melf_i386", which in itself is a bit weird when doing a custom linker script - but this means that he's targetting ELF i386, which means that he wants to produce a 32-bit ELF binary. Usually when you're doing kernel work on 32-bit machines, you're not targetting ELF, as a 32-bit Intel CPU cannot just boot off an ELF image.

Comment: I think the issue is that we don't know why the OP is using that tutorial - it is a X-Y problem

Comment: Yes, exactly - I commented to him on his other question that this is an XY problem. He will need to detail why he wants to do this - or link to the tutorial he's following, otherwise it is impossible to give advise.