# How to get all GNU tools on MacOS 11?

Tags: terminal, command-line, homebrew, unix

I already know about binutils `brew install binutils`, but it is missing a specific command I need: `ld`, as mentioned in this other question of mine: [MacOS equivalent for Ubuntu Linker (ld) command?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/419800/macos-equivalent-for-ubuntu-linker-ld-command)

I am aware that MacOS Command Line Tools contains `ld`, but it does not feature the options and parameters that my specific case requires.

Thank you.

Comment: This is really an XY question... I think you would get your problem solved faster by asking how to achieve what it is you want to do with the linker script, rather than focusing on getting linker scripts working. Most probably you can achieve the same without a linker script at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wouldn't make sense to install the GNU `ld` command on macOS, unless you're doing some sort of cross-compiling, which you're not.

Basically, the GNU version of `ld` doesn't know how to make executables that can run on macOS. Hypothetically, installing and using it, would not produce anything that works.

You will want to use the standard macOS `ld` command instead.